# Perform a Natural Deduction with No Logical Equivalencies

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, solution-verification, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

Prove:

$$\frac{(a \land b) \rightarrow (b \leftrightarrow c)}{\therefore a \rightarrow(b \rightarrow c)}$$

**My conclusion:**
$1.\space(a \land b) \rightarrow (b \leftrightarrow c) \qquad Premise.$
$\boxed{ 2. \space a \qquad \qquad Assumption. \\ \boxed{3. \space b \qquad \qquad Assumption. \\ 4. \space a \land b \qquad \land-intro\space(2,3)\\ 5. \space b \leftrightarrow c \qquad \rightarrow-elim(1,4) \\ 6. \space c \qquad \qquad \leftrightarrow-elim(3,5)}  \\7. \space b \rightarrow c \qquad \rightarrow -intro (3-6)
}$
$8. \space a \rightarrow (b\rightarrow c) \quad \rightarrow-intro(2-7)$

Here I am asking to see if my steps to the conclusion are right. I am not super clear on the "correct" way to go about this problem. I know that I am assuming things to be true and drawing conclusions based on what I have assumed and what comes out with the statements I deduct from.

Some insight on this problem and if someone could validate my work would me very helpful.

Comment: Well done. Your proof is correct. Do you have a specific question ?

Comment: My question is, in these kind of proofs we want to see the truth value of each "variable?" For this one we want to see the truth value of b, and then c, then we can draw the conclusion that a is also true? I am trying to understand how these proofs are supposed to work.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "we want to see the truth value of each variable" ? In a nutshell, as the argument you posted is valid, there is a proof — you just provided one. Using a truth table, you could check that, whenever $(a \land b) \rightarrow (b \leftrightarrow c)$ is true, $a \rightarrow(b \rightarrow c)$ is true. In other words, there are no rows where all premises are true and conclusion is false.

Comment: What you explained makes complete sense. The truth table really helps me in this because I can see specifically why this is true. I wanted to wrap my head around the big idea of why we are doing the proof rather than just doing it. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. I think a natural deduction proof gives some insight into the structure of an argument. From a practical perspective, the truth table of this argument has eight rows. But suppose you had an argument with 8 variables, then the number of rows would be $2^8$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your derivation is correct. The assumtions are perfect, since your conlusion has only (→) you have to use the "practical rule" of I→ that states: "assume the antecedent of the formula you want to derivate and try to derivate the consequent". In this case you had to do it twice since your conclusion is (a →(b → c)). You have to assume (a) and try to derivate (b → c) and in order to get (b → c) you have to assume (b) and try to get (c).